# MongooseServerSelectionError ECONNREFUSED for multiple database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I have a NodeJS app with Mongoose and I have two mongodb databases to connect. Every one is in their own container (app, mongodb1, mongodb2). `mongodb1` has 27017 exposed and `mongodb2` has 27018 exposed.

My app is not throwing any error when connecting to mongodb1 but it throws MongooseServerSelectionError ECONNREFUSED when connecting to mongodb2.

I'm using 'mongodb://mongodb2:27018' to connect from the app.

If I use MongoDB Compass from my Windows host to connect to 'mongodb://localhost:27018', it works fine.

In the app container, I get normal response when running `ping mongodb2` or `ping mongodb2:27018`. It seems reachable.

More details:

- Node version: 18.19.1
- Mongoose version: 8.2.0

`docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                      NAMES
3d011a43e3d4   app:1.0.0         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes   0.0.0.0:4030->4030/tcp     app
efad9f43c7f1   custom-mongodb2:1.0.0   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes   0.0.0.0:27018->27017/tcp   mongodb2
418fbe9bc9c8   custom-mongodb1:1.0.0     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb1
```

Comment: How are you creating the containers? What does `docker ps` look like?

Comment: I have a docker compose file. I updated the question with the docker ps